# Centering an item in cases environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments, cases

I wish to center the 1 in the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{align*}
v'(k,\CS)=
\begin{cases}
    \displaystyle\frac{G_{max}(k){-}q_k'(CS)}{G_{max}(k){-}\Gmin(k)} & \text{if }G_{max}(k) {\neq} G_{min}(k) \\
    1                                                                &  \text{if }G_{max}(k) {=}G_{min}(k)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

The image of the LaTeX is shown below:

> [image]

Comment: Off-topic comment: Don't enclose the `=`, `-` and `\neq` symbols in curly braces, as doing so messes with TeX's spacing around binary (such as `-`) and relational operators (such as `\leq` and `=`). Conversely, *do* encase the "min" and "max" subscript strings in either `\text{...}` or `\textup{...}` so that they don't get interpreted as strings of variables (m, a, and x; m, i, and n).

Answer (score 18):

Environment `cases` of package `amsmath` internally uses environment `array` with columns of type `l`. The column specification is `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`. Thus `\multicolumn` will work:

```
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\quad}}{1}
```

Also an easier way is possible.
The justification code of `array`/`tabular` just adds an `\hfil` at the right side of a column of type `l`. This moves the cell contents to the left. By adding `\hfil` to the left, the contents is centered. Adding `\hfill` would overrule the right `\hfil` and the contents would be moved to the right.
Thus the code for centering is:

```
\hfil 1
```

The full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  v'(k,CS)=
  \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{G_{\text{max}}(k) - q_k'(CS)}
          {G_{\text{max}}(k) - G_{\text{min}}(k)}
    & \text{if }G_{\text{max}}(k) \neq G_{\text{min}}(k) \\
    % \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\quad}}{1} % variant with \multicolumn
    \hfil 1                    % variant with \hfil
    & \text{if }G_{\text{max}}(k) = G_{\text{min}}(k)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Various code errors of the incomplete MWE are corrected.
- Text subscripts "min" and "max" are put in `\text{...}`.
- The braces around binary operators and relational symbols are removed to correct the spacing around the symbols. (Adding braces makes these symbols to `\mathord` atoms without additional spacing.)
- Package `amsmath` provides the shorthand `\dfrac` for `\displaystyle\frac`.

### Brace of environment `cases`

The environment `cases` uses `\left\lbrace` … `\right.` to set the left curly brace. I think, the reason that `\lbrace` is preferred over `\{` in the code is optimization. `\{` is defined as (`latex.ltx`):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
```

- Robustness is not needed, because macro `\end` is not robust because of `\@checkend`.
- We are already in math mode, thus testing for the mode can be saved.

At the right side an empty delimiter is needed because `\left` and `\right` has to be used in properly nested pairs. But `\right.` will add the space `\nulldelimiterspace`. If environment is always the latest element of a line, then this space can be made available by redefining the end part of `cases`:

```
\def\endcases{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

Comment: If I'm just in time to ask this to someone with `more^n` experience than me: if the `cases` is defined by `array`, *how the left delimiter is defined, in terms of code, inside `amsmath`?*. I don't know if I could add this as a real question though...sorry for this.

Comment: @AndreaL.: It's already in the answer, the full column specification for `array` is `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`. That means two left aligned columns without spaces at the left and right of the array and `\quad` inbetween the columns.

Comment: Got it, now I'll have to study more on the usage of `amsmath` package now that I'm preparing my first thesis (thanks) :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - I think Andrea is asking which command generates the left-hand curly brace; for the record, it's `\left\lbrace`.

Comment: @Mico, I knew the definition, but I do not know how it is exactly implemented in the code of `amsmath`'s `cases` to be different from `\left\{\begin{array}...`

Comment: @Mico, Mmh... I'd say it's interesting * *quote from Spock* *. In seriousness I'd think I found the code "responsable" to this behaviour so maybe I'll add this as a future question. Thanks for the time though.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, I had read the comment too fast. I have now added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek Many thanks for the explanation (added even +1).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Thanks for providing these additional explanations regarding the use of `\lbrace`; I will delete my (erroneous!) note in which I speculated as to why `\{` wasn't used.

Comment: I cannot understand why in my case `\hfil` does not work, but `\hfill` does.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus The example of the answer still works with `\hfil`. I do not know "your  case", maybe, you are using a package that changes internals of `amsmath`. You can try the alternative with `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `array` environment as faked `cases` by delimiting it with `\left\{` and `\right.`, so that you can adjust the horizontal alignment with the letters `cl` as Centered and Left aligned.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
%
\[
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-2.5pt}  % local modifications
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
v'(k,CS)= 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{cl}  % first column is centered
  \dfrac{G_{max}(k)-q_k'(CS)}{G_{max}(k)-G_{min}(k)} & \text{if }G_{max}(k)\neq G_{min}(k) \\
  1                                                  & \text{if }G_{max}(k)=G_{min}(k)
 \end{array}
\right.
\]
%
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

> [image]

By the way, you can enlarge the distance between the rows by simply adding more lenght to `\arraystretch` locally, or if you want to apply this rule generally you can define a new environment in the preamble of your document:

```
\newenvironment{MyCases}{%
 \addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-2.5pt}%
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
 \left\{\begin{array}%
}{%
 \end{array}\right.%
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I copied the argument of the cases environment, now I'm editing one bit at time, and have to be fast at this, whew! :-)

Comment: Don't worry...!

Comment: @karlkoeller, now finished. It's always a pleasure to share knowledge (this time to someone with more rep than me ;-)