# How to typeset piecewise functions

Tags: amsmath, cases

I don't know what the big `{` thing is called so can't search and when tried and write in LaTeX and didn't find this expression or structure in word either.

[image]

Comment: Oh look, recursive algorithms analysis. :)

Comment: This site is not about WORD ;-)

Comment: It's called a [_piecewise_-defined function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}          %loads amsmath as well
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Floor\lfloor\rfloor
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Ceil\lceil\rceil

\begin{document}
\[
  T(n) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $n=1$} \\
                                   1 & \text{if $n=2$} \\
  T(\Floor{n/2}) + T(\Ceil{n/2}) + 2 & \text{if $n>2$}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your choice of alignment in the source file is odd and moreso because it's completely different from the output obtained. I'd surely align the `&`s but I'd align the first part of the lines on the left (so `0` and `1` aligned with `T(` instead of the `+ 2`). I understand the reasoning behind aligning numbers but having that much spaces looks strange and it's hard to see what's there in the first two rows, besides it suggest the false idea that the output would resemble that alignment which is false.

Comment: `& \text{if $n=1$}` is easier.

Comment: @egreg Easier in what sense? It's two extra keystrokes and presumably more work for the compiler, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Easier to read from the typescript.

Comment: @egreg: `& if $n=1$`  is still easier, using the `cases* ` environment from `mathtools`.

Comment: @Bernard Of course.

Comment: @Bakuriu Personal preference, of course :) My eyes have a harder time matching up the different cells appropriately for reading.  Personally, I don't get any such suggestion about what the output looks like from the source file – I just care about what the document *means* – the quicker I can read it, the quicker I can figure that out :) *But*, if it's quicker for you to read it right-aligned, by all means :)

Comment: @egreg I used to do that, but the idea of switching out of math mode and then immediately back into it just seems…weird to me. But alas, if it's easier to read, it's of course better (assuming there are no side-effects?) :)  **Edit** I ran a diff of a PDF produced with both methods – there is no difference.  `\text{if $n=1$}` should be preferred.

Answer (score 6):

With only a *partial* alignment, due to the long last line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools} %loads amsmath as well
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Floor⎣⎦
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Ceil⎣⎦

\begin{document}

\[ T(n) =
  \begin{cases*}
    0 \quad& if $ n = 1 $ \\
    1 & if $ n = 2 $ \\
    \mathrlap{T(\Floor{n/2}) + T(\Ceil{n/2}) + 2 \quad \text{if } n > 2}
  \end{cases*}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to obtain the desired result in LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
T(n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                0 & \hspace{5mm} n=1 \\
                1 & \hspace{5mm} n=2 \\
                T( \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor) + T(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil
                      )+ 2 & \hspace{5mm} n > 2 \\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Use `cases` from `amsmath`.

Comment: Why use an `align` environment if there's nothing to be aligned?

Comment: As stated, this is one way to obtain the desired results. This leaves room for other possible ways.

Comment: From looking at the image in the question, I don't think it's _desired_ for the 0, 1, and longer expression to be centered. In addition, if the extra space between columns is really wanted, there are much better ways than to add it manually in every row.

Comment: @PaulGessler What do you suggest for adding spaces?

Comment: @Jeff a few options are shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133280/centering-an-item-in-cases-environment