# What's diffrence between these cases? / cases formatting centering

Tags: pdftex, cases

I want my pdf cases to look like that

[image: look i want]

When I try to do it myself, I have this effect:

[image: My pdf]

Here is my latex code:

```latex
\begin{equation*}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{x-1} & \textrm{dla}\quad x<-1, \\
2\sin{\pi x} & \textrm{dla}\quad x \in \langle -1,3), \\
\frac{3x+1}{8x} & \textrm{dla}\quad x \in \langle 3,6 \rangle , \\
4x^3 & \textrm{dla}\quad x>6.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Please fix my code

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** now is considered @Barbara Beeton comment.

Not with `cases` but `array` works fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
g(x)=
\left\{\begin{array}{clc}
\frac{x}{x-1}   & \textrm{dla}  & x<-1, \\
2\sin{\pi x}    & \textrm{dla}  & x \in \langle -1,3), \\
\frac{3x+1}{8x} & \textrm{dla}  & x \in \langle 3,6 \rangle , \\
4x^3            & \textrm{dla}  & x>6.
\end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

If you like to have bigger vertical space between lined, add afte `\]` command `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}`. Then r5esult is:

[image]

Comment: You really don't need the `\quad`; the space there is nicely taken care of by the `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right! I just blindly copied OP comment. Corrected noe. Thank you very much for tip!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133283/199568) helpful. You just add `\hfill` on the left and right side side of the content you want to be centered. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\hfill \frac{x}{x-1}\hfill & \textrm{dla}\quad \hfill x<-1,\hfill \\
\hfill 2\sin{\pi x}\hfill & \textrm{dla}\quad \hfill  x \in \langle -1,3),\hfill \\
\hfill \frac{3x+1}{8x}\hfill & \textrm{dla}\quad \hfill x \in \langle 3,6 \rangle ,\hfill \\
\hfill 4x^3\hfill & \textrm{dla}\quad \hfill  x>6.\hfill
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]